# How do I manage request codes android with more readability?

Tags: java, android, http, callback, request

I wish to find a better way of handling responses than the method I was taught by the company that I worked for.

I was taught to use a generic HttpClient, that used volley to send the requests. The client had a static method that would be given a generic listener, ResponseListener, which would make the callback to the context when a volley response came through. The ResponseListener would keep track of all the request "type"s . That is the code given to the client so that the context can differentiate between requests.

Is there any other way of keeping track of all the request codes without having to keep one big directory type interface file? It becomes quite overwhelming to look at when you get past 100 requests. Then you write wrapper functions for the codes in the client, and it too gets messy.

HttpClient

```
public static void doRequestString(final ResponseListener listener, final int type, final String url, final JSONObject postData) {
    // Request a string response
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Result handling
                listener.onRequestDone(type, response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Error handling
            System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

    request.setTag(context);
    VolleyClient.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().add(request);

}
```

Listener

```
public interface ResponseListener
{
    int HELLO_REQUEST = 0;
    int GOODBYE_REQUEST = 1;
    // every other request numbered here, so they don't conflict

    void onRequestDone(int type, String response);
}
```

Context

```
public void onRequestDone(int type, String response)
{
    switch(type) {
        case Response.Listener.HELLO_REQUEST:
            handleHello();
            break;
        case Response.Listener.GOODBYE_REQUEST:
            handleGoodbye();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are not that many options, to be honest. You are dealing with your responses in a centralised manner right now. Another option would be stripping the request type as having a listener per request. The main disadvantage here is that you will get your code full of listeners.

I would suggest you try and combine the two approaches in a way that suites your use case. Maybe create an intermediate service layer, divide your functionality by some of their property (for example logically - all user requests grouped together, etc), expose a single listener per service and manage the request codes there. This way you can have a bit of modularity.

Comment: I started thinking about the second paragraph you suggested. I think this makes most sense. I will wait a few days to see if any better suggestions come forward, if they do not, I will accept yours.